# Netmask for point to point ip address?

Tags: ip, linux-networking, tunneling, ifconfig, tunnel

In a point to point tunnel, I was able to have the same IP twice. It looks like a bug, I think that might be related to some internal representation of the netmask. It can be reproduced with the steps below.

I created a tun tunnel like this:

```
ip tuntap add dev tun3 mode tun user alice group alice
ip address add 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 dev tun3
```

I listed the address:

```
$ ip address list dev tun3
…
inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun3
…
```

As you see, there seems to be no netmask associated with 10.8.0.1. But ifconfig reports /32:

```
$ ifconfig tun3
…
inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.2
…
```

If I use `iproute2` to add the same address 10.8.0.1/32, there is no error, the address is added and then listed.

```
# ip address add 10.8.0.1/32 dev tun3
$ ip address list dev tun3
…
inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun3
…
inet 10.8.0.1/32 scope global tun3
…
```

The question is, why? I was expecting a:

```
    RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

In case you wonder why I would try this, I was trying to help with [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/998907/same-ip-twice-in-the-same-interface).

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using `ifconfig` for IP assignment you could stick to use of `ip` from iproute2 package. Its manual describes this quite clearly:

`man ip-address`: "…

> **peer ADDRESS** the address of the remote endpoint for pointopoint interfaces. Again, the ADDRESS *may be followed by a slash and a decimal number, encoding the network prefix length*. *If a peer address is specified, the local address cannot have a prefix length*. *The network prefix is associated with the peer rather than with the local address*.

…"

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. I updated the steps to reproduce it, sticking to `iproute2` and the additional address is listed anyway. It seems the local ip address of the tunnel is somehow _netmask-less_.

Comment: That has everything to do with that. It's explained in the manual itself: "local address cannot have a prefix length".

Comment: Please read the _full_ quote in your answer. You cannot have a prefix length **because** _the network prefix is associated with the peer rather than with the local address._ I might be wrong, but it looks to me like the local address does have a network prefix, related to that of the peer. What is it, a /32? If yes, I should not be able to duplicate the address. If not a /32, which one then?

Comment: "Please read the full quote in your answer" — so you've started reading manuals. I welcome that. ;)